# Wordpress Error on Actual site

Tags: wordpress, web

> // function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us17.list-manage.com","uuid":"020a9070e7987e17b3894681a","lid":"1e16a2b67d"}) })

I am receiving this error code on top of the web page that USERS can also see.
For reference, I've also attached a picture of the same.

[image]

Comment: It looks like someone's commented something out, but in a place where it's rendering to the page still. If you inspect the element with your browser's dev tools, you should be able to find where in the DOM it's sitting that should guide you to where it is in your wordpress theme / plugins / whatever.

Comment: I've tried it. It is not working. can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Not really, with the level of detail you provide. When I go to that URL I do not see that message, fwiw.